# How can I print session cookies in python?

Tags: python, cookies

I tried to print my requests cookies session with this Code(requests)

```
print(session.cookies.get_dict())
```

and

```
session_cookies = session.cookies
cookies_dictionary = session_cookies.get_dict()
print(cookies_dictionary)
```

but I only get this as an output:

```
{}
```

Comment: Which module or library are you using to create the session object, `requests`, `urllib3`?

Comment: Im using requests

Comment: Are you sure the url that you are calling is sending/setting cookies? If the server is not setting cookies, the cookies dict will be empty. For e.g., `session.get('http://example.com') `doesn't set cookies whereas `session.get('http://google.com')` does.